# Failed to start session on 16.04 (CAN'T access terminal typing CTR+ALT+F1 either)

Tags: 16.04, login, tty, session

I installed updates for Ubuntu and was asked to reboot. Whenever I try and login in to my account I get a 'failed to start session' same goes for when I try to login as a guest. I can't get to the terminal either. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't work on my mac keyboard.

Comment: Did you change to a TTY successfully anytime before? Is there a `Fn` you may have to hold? Did you try `Opt`+`Ctrl`+`F1` instead?

Comment: Holding down Fn key worked and I was able to get into terminal and doing the required updates. Was able to login! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are keyboards where the <kbd>F</kbd>-keys have special functions like volume control – to reach a TTY you may actually have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**<kbd>Fn</kbd>**+<kbd>F1</kbd>…<kbd>F6</kbd> in such a case.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.